# Route 53 record pointing to s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have got my hosted zone `exmple.com`. I also created the s3 bucket `example-photos` for storing my photos. Normally, photos in s3 bucket are available under the following url
`https://example-photos.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/photo1.png`
However, I would like to create a subdomain `bucket.example.com` and let the photos from `example-photos` bucket be available under the subdomain url like `https://bucket.example.com/photo1.png`

What record should I create in `Route 53` then?

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on [Tutorial: Configuring a static website using a custom domain registered with Route 53 - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html)? For a start, the bucket needs the same name as the domain.

Answer (score 0):

To make your photos in the S3 bucket available under the subdomain URL, you need to create a CNAME record in Route 53 that points the subdomain to the endpoint of your S3 bucket. The CNAME record tells Route 53 to resolve the subdomain to the S3 endpoint, allowing you to access your photos at the subdomain URL.

```json
{
    "Comment": "CNAME record for S3 bucket",
    "Changes": [
        {
            "Action": "CREATE",
            "ResourceRecordSet": {
                "Name": "bucket.example.com",
                "Type": "CNAME",
                "TTL": 300,
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "example-photos.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```bash
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id YOUR_HOSTED_ZONE_ID --change-batch file://recordset.json
```

Comment: I got the error 
`
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
`

when trying to open `bucket.example.com` page.
My bucket is public btw

Comment: @user123145152323 Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316277/cname-to-s3-bucket-amazon). This is your case. I hope it helps. Thank you